# Make function run every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server running with the following code. I want the function `callAPI` to be called every two seconds, pardoning the hours between 2:00am-5:18am. The API reports that I'm making more than 37,260 API calls per day (0.5 call/second * 60seconds/minute * 60 minutes/hour * (24-3.3) hours). Any reason why this would run the function callAPI more often than 37,260 times per day?

```
function callAPI(callback) {
  // Do API call
  callback()
}

function timer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  if (hour == 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callAPI(timer);
    }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3.3); // Set timeout to 3.3 hours (resumes at 5:18)
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callAPI(timer);
    }, 2000); // 2 seconds
  }
}

callAPI(timer)
```

Comment: How has it been run - could it have been set off multiple times?

Comment: How many does the API say you're using? You should use setInterval here instead of setTimeout.

Comment: How many instances of your node app are you running ? you should make sure you're only running one instance. Also , I would log every request to a file using a library like winston https://github.com/winstonjs/winston just to be sure why and when its happening

Comment: @TristanFoureur Does Node handle setInterval better than browsers then? Because if you're after accurate gaps between calls setInterval is normally best avoided when doing something like this. Although I suppose it really depends on what that function does and what the OP does and doesn't want to happen regarding overlaps

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I spawn the server via PM2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). TristanFoureur, The API cuts off at at the limit so I cannot see the exact number. Charbz, I am only running one instance through this. Thanks for the recommendation for Winston– I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The getHours function returns a number between 0 and 23.

So you may be getting 12 * 60 * 30 additional calls to the second branch in your if statement, per day.

Comment: Could you please explain further? It seems getHours will always return 2 at some point each day and appropriately timeout by 3.3 hours.

Comment: You are correct, it will return a 2 once a day, at 3AM. Currently your expectations for the code seems to assume a 12 hour day rather than 24 hour day.

Comment: Actually, something doesn't quite add up ... how many additional calls are you getting exactly?

Comment: The API cuts off at at the limit so I cannot see the exact number. The limit is 50,000, so it's making a minimum of ~13,000 extra calls (50,000 - 37,260). 

Actually, I only want the function to not be called between the hours of 2am-5:18am. 2pm-5:18pm is fine, as are the rest of the hours.